# Django queryset fuzzy search

Tags: django

I hope you can help me - I am not sure what to search to find the answer.

I have a Django queryset returned to my HTML template.

I want to have an autocomplete search based on that queryset. So if I have 'Banana', 'Apple' and 'Orange' as my query results, when someone types Or it should show Orange as an example.

How would I even go about doing that? Can javascript interact with the queryset objects or is there a simple way to do it?

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into [json_script](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script).

This outputs a Python object as JSON, so that it can be used with JS.